# What are all the Straw Hats' dreams?

Tags: one-piece

For the starting members like Zoro, Nami, etc. it is clearly stated what their dreams are. But for the newer members like Jinbei and Franky, they are not so clear.

Dreams are very important in *One Piece* and for some time, I thought having a dream that sounded stupidly impossible to everyone else is a clear requirement for being a Straw Hat. But not so much now.

Answer (score 3):

- Luffy: the Pirate King

1. Zoro: greatest swordsman
2. Ussop: a great warrior
3. Nami: draw a map of the whole world
4. Sanji: get to see the All Blue
5. Robin: learn all about the history of the world
6. Chopper: be able to cure every disease
7. Franky: make the best ship in all seas
8. Brook: meet Laboon again
9. Jinbei: have Fish-Men live with humans

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While we appreciate anyone's contribution, note that pure opinion/speculative answer is discouraged. Instead, consider [edit]ing and trying to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think about the dreams of all the members. All Straw Hat dreams:-

- **Luffy** - Secret dream (needs to become Pirate King).

1. Zoro - World's no. 1 swordsman (to let his name reach the heavens).
2. Nami - Draw the true map of the whole world.
3. Ussop - A brave warrior of the sea (to be able to do things he lies about).
4. Sanji - Find the "All Blue". (maybe, to be able to cook anything anytime).
5. Chopper - To be able to cure any disease in the world.
6. Robin - Find the true history of the world (fulfill Ohara's legacy).
7. Franky - Make a ship capable of going anywhere in the world and see it do that.
8. Brook - Meet Labbon at the end of Grand Line (the whale nakama of Rumbar Pirates).
9. Jinbei - Bring the Fishmen above the sea and abolish their discrimination.
10. ??? -- ??? (mysterious 10th member).

Answer (score 0):

The dreams of the current members of the Straw Hat Pirates are :

1. Luffy - Become The Pirate King
2. Zoro - Become The Greatest Swordsman In The World
3. Nami - Draw A World Map
4. Sanji - Find The All Blue
5. Robin - Learn All The History Of The World
6. Chopper - Be Able To Cure Every Disease
7. Usopp - Be A Great Warrior Of The Sea
8. Jimbei - FishMen and Humans Live Together
9. Franky - Build A Ship Capable Of Going Anywhere In The World
10. Brook - Meet Laboon

Comment: This has the exact same issue as the previous answers in that it doesn't provide any references. Could you, for example, find manga panels in which they express these dreams?